# How does Newton's third law hold up when a block kept on a table breaks the table?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, free-body-diagram

Suppose there's a block of some mass that is kept on a table. But, instead of staying at rest on the table, it breaks through the table. How does Newton's third law hold up here?

If the block is at rest on the table then the push of the block *onto the table* due to its weight and the normal force by the table *on the block* are the action-reaction forces. But what about this case?

Comment: Newtons thirds law still applies, but now parts of the table and the block are accelerating downwards. The forces are smaller, but they are still equal. Can you explain in more detail which aspect of the problem you are struggling with?

Comment: I can't understand how does the block break through the table if the force the block and the table apply on each other are equal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The law still applies, but we have to be careful with the forces.  If the book has a mass $m$, we cannot simply say that the book applies a force of $F=mg$.  If the table broke, then there was some maximum force it could withstand, which was less than $mg$.

The key to remember is that the sum of the forces on an object equals 0 **only** if that object is not accelerating.  It actually always equals $ma$, where $a$ is the acceleration on the object. We write this $\sum F = ma$, with $\sum$ being how we notate summing everything up.  It just happens to be that if the object is not accelerating (we say "at rest") $\sum F = m\cdot 0 = 0$

So the reality in your scenario is that the table pushes up with some force equal to exactly the amount of force it could apply  without breaking.  This is less than $mg$, so the result is that the book is accelerating.  Newton's Third Law holds.

Now very soon this book will start moving closer to the atoms in the table.  To understand what happens beyond the breaking point, we can't treat the table as one monolithic entity -- the velocity of the different parts can be different, and will be different during breaking.  We can analyze the individual pieces of wood, or we can go to extremes and look at the forces on the atoms.  But that all goes beyond your question.  The fundamental answer is that the sum of the forces does not have to be zero, unless the object is not accelerating.

And much of these questions can be answered by remembering that there's many operations that we think of as "instantaneous" but are not.  If the book falls on the table and WHAM! makes a loud sound, we say it "hit" the table at that time.  But, if you look in slow motion, you will see that there was a whole lot of bending and wobbling which let that "hit" work out according to Newton's Laws. For example, in cases like these, the table can't "break" right away. It's actually a long series of smaller motions which, over the course of a few milliseconds, result in what we call "breaking."

Comment: I can't understand that how can the book apply a force of *mg* and the table only apply its maximum withstandable force. If the table applies a certain amount of force on the book, then the book should also be applying that much force on the table, according to the law. Also, to what you said in the first paragraph, if the book is accelerating it would have to apply a force greater than the max withstandable force to break through, right? Could you please clarify a bit on this?

Comment: @AxSmasher, the book *doesn't* apply a force of $mg$ to the table.

Comment: @AxSmasher BowlOfRed is right.  The book does **not** apply a force of $mg$.  Ask yourself why you feel it is obliged to.  It isn't an immediate consequence of newton's 3rd law.  The Force of the table on the book is not the reactionary force to the force of gravity.  The force of the table on the book is the recationary force of the book on the table.  That is all.

Comment: The challenge you are having is *really* common.  You get taught that all of the forces equal out.  Well, in this case, they absolutely do not.  There *must* be accelerations in the scenario you describe.  I think the confusion comes from how we have to teach.  We typically teach static situations first -- ones with no motion, and thus no acceleration.  In those situations, the forces on any object sum to 0.  We then teach Newton's 3rd law, which says that every force has an equal and oppoisite reaction force.

Comment: And its tremendously easy to mix the two together, and try to apply the rules of statics simply because we saw a reaction force.  But we can't.  The scenario you give is absolutely a dynamic one with accelerations, and we can't apply the rules of statics... but we can apply newton's 3rd law.

Comment: I get it, I had been looking at it the wrong way...thanks

Comment: I find it always helpful to think about the reality of a situation even though this physics problem postulates a perfectly rigid table. Think of the table as a bunch of big stiff springs (which it is), the book doesn't cause the reactive force to exist, it is instead the bending of the table that generates the force. What happens when you place a book on the table is that while the book is falling it's also bending the table. If the table is strong enough it'll generate a force strong enough to stop the book; if it's not strong enough it keeps bending until it breaks.

Comment: @CortAmmon How can you say that the force the book applies is not mg? Force of any object is mg, and the book no doubt exerts a force due to gravity pulling which must mean it is mg.

Comment: @Ihavemanyquestions The force of gravity on the book is always mg.  This does not mean it always applies that much force on other objects.  It only does so when not accelerating.  It is these other forces that matter when talking about striking a table. 
 The trivial example of this principle would be free fall, where the book is accelerating at 9.8 m/s2 and exerts *no* forces on other objects.

Comment: @CortAmmon Thanks for the reply. Could you clarify a bit more? If an accelerating object does NOT exert a force on other objects... isn't that what momentum and drag is? A flying object exerts a force on the air molecules which in turn creates drag on the object. The object would also exert a pretty strong force onto a body if it were to hit it, like a ball smashing into a window. In fact if it hit you, isn't that the force exerted by the object due to acceleration?

Comment: @Ihavemanyquestions Its not that accelerating objects don't exert forces, its that the particular case of exerting *exactly* 9.8m/s2 * m is only true for a block that is not accelerating (and is otherwise only affected by gravity and the force of the table).  If it is accelerating, it can still exert a force, it will merely be a different force.  The rule is F=ma.  The sum of the forces is equal to the mass times the acceleration. If acceleration is 0, then the sum of the forces is 0, and that makes it very easy to compute forces. If acceleration is nonzero, the calculuations are more complex.

Comment: "Breaking," as the table does in the question, yields a particularly complicated scenario because some of the force is transmitted directly through the table into the floor, while some of the force is transmitted into the shards of table, *and* on top of that the block is accelerating.  Quite messy.

Answer (score 4):

In the case where the table holds, we have a lot of information:

- The book is not accelerating
- The book has mass $m$
- The only vertical forces on the book are gravity and the normal force from the table.

Given the lack of acceleration, we know the total vertical forces on the book must sum to zero and $F_N = mg$.  The weight of the book is entirely supported by the table.  The force of the book on the table and the force of the table on the book are equal in magnitude.

When the book breaks through the table, the first assumption no longer holds.    The total forces on the book no longer sum to zero.  Gravity is still the same, so the only thing that can have changed is the normal force from the table.  Instead of remaining equal to $mg$, the normal force is less.

This is not a problem to Newton's third law.  The force the book is placing on the table is also less.

Comment: "When the book breaks through the table, the first assumption no longer holds." ie the book is now accelerating. Fine. But the question is WHY. If the table breaks, the force that gravity exerts on the book is still the same as when the table didn't break. Gravity is ALWAYS pulling, even satellites in orbit. The difference is that the table is too weak to withstand the force of the book exerting on the table due to gravity's pulling. "too weak" is precisely the inability to exert an equal&opp force since if it has to be "strong enough" to exert an equal&opp force to stop it falling through.

Answer (score 3):

There is always some amount of material deformation when two objects are held against each other by a force. In this case material deformation of the table exceeds its structural integrity, so it breaks. Now your action reaction pair is the block falling towards the Earth and the Earth falling towards the block. Since Earth's mass is so much greater than the block's mass the Earth's movement is negligible but not zero.

Comment: Precisely that structural integrity is broken means some extra force, more than an equal and opposite force that it is supposed to be able to withstand, must have broken the structural integrity. The question is WHY if they are supposed to provide an equal and opposite force.

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to think of an analogy, such as an arm-wrestling or a tug-of-war match.

During much of the match, both combatants may be applying equal force, and there's no motion (in actual practice it's hard to be consistent, so there will be some fluctuation back and forth, but we can simplify this). But eventually one of them will weaken more than the other; when the forces become significantly unbalanced, the stronger player(s) will overcome the weaker ones, and the match will end.

This is what's going on between the block and the table. Gravity is applying a downward force on the block, while the table's rigidity counteracts that, so there's no motion. But the continual force being applied to the table is slowly breaking the bonds that provide its rigidity. If this goes on long enough, there will be enough bonds broken that the table can't provide an equal upward force. Gravity wins the match and the block breaks through.

Answer (score -2):

first u have to understand action reaction forces of book kept on table ..let's check.1) the earth attract the book by mg and the book attract the earth by same force mg...(2). The table attract the book and the book attract the table...now unfortunately when the earth apply a force on book mg and book apply force mg but book get attracted towards earth due to less mass and earth remain at its own position
But before the book coming to earth the table disturbed the book ...but also now the book get attract by mg by earth....so a force is applied on table by book and same ammount of force applied by table on book..but the earth still accelerate the book by mg and the breaking strenghth of table is less than mg so table broke and book gets attracted towards earth...

Let's this case in space ..where no gravity present now kept a book on table ...than there is only on action reaction pair is that the table attract the book and book attract the table...that's all..bro i think u get ur ans...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).